# combined list in global navigation of responsive web design

Tags: css

my homepage: http://red2.net/rwd2/

go to my homepage and..

**problem 1.** if you mouseover to global navigation such as 메인, 게임, 컨텐츠,

now appear submenu. but submenu's list is combined.(see red arrow in below image)

i tried many css styles, but don't work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtsJp.png

**problem 2.** i add to global navigation style 'text-indent:-9999px;' but this style don't work and text still alive.

sorry for bad english.

thanks.

Comment: your submenu lists are absolutely positioned. Try changing it to relative.